# iOS App Store Copyright Rejection

Tags: ios

We are developing an App. for a client and need to release it under our Developer Account.

How can we provide advance notice or written documentation proving that we have permission to use a 3rd party's intellectual property in our app? (e.g. Brand names and logos, graphic assets, etc.)

Comment: you can mention it in the notes while uploading or in case your app is rejected with the same reason, give proof over there and contest the app rejection.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#intellectual-property)

> 5.2.2 Third Party Sites/Services: If your app uses, accesses, monetizes access to, or displays content from a third party service,
>   ensure that you are specifically permitted to do so under the
>   service’s terms of use. **Authorization must be provided upon request.**

Emphasis mine.

The section before it does also address your situation, with the (unhelpful to you) caveat that it should be submitted by the owner.

Ultimately, Apple will contact you if they have questions and you can deal with it then.